# Jar file in classpath not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run the Eclipse batch compiler from command Line. So i have my command as follows: `java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core_xxx.jar -classpath my/path/to/first/.jar:rt.jar file_in_current_directory.java`. But i get this `import xyz cannot be resolved` error even though that class is present in the classpath. Could any body help? I am working in Linux Redhat. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you use `-jar` the `-classpath` argument is ignored.

Comment: Yes, you need a manifest in your jar.

Comment: Did you miss the name of the file here `my/path/to/first/.jar`? Is `rt.jar` in your current directory?

Comment: Nope, I have the correct path for the first jar. The rt.jar is in my current directory. i copied it from the JDK location. And also, I am using this guide http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-ant_javac_adapter.htm to help me. So, I do not understand why -classpath was ignored.

Comment: Because that's how the `-jar` argument works. Read the launcher docs; it's pretty explicit about this: "When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html The docs are your friend.